# How do I restrict an input to a certain value?

Tags: android

I am still new in android and java and I am wondering how to restrict input to a certain value? Example:- if the input is for a Phone number, the keypad will show numeric pad by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `EditText.textInputType` and set it to `number`.

More info here https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, you can use the inputType attribute. You can set this to **phone**, **text**, **password**, etc. It all depends on the type of input you want the user to type in. Here's an illustration.

```
<EditText
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/editText"
     android:inputType="phone" />
```

Read more about EditText attributes [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText). I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: Thank you so much!